# Inheritence using both the parent attribute and overriden child attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I am using inheritance. In one of my methods I would like to use both the parent attribute and the over-riden child attribute together. Something like;

```
class Parent(object):
    att = 'parent'

    def my_meth(self):
        return super().att + self.att

class Child(Parent):
    att = 'child'

print(Child().my_meth())
```

Which would print;

> parentchild

However the above code gives the error;

> 'super' object has no attribute 'options'

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you tried with `return super().__thisclass__.att + self.att`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way I can think of accessing a static attribute of the parent class that gets overridden by the child is to directly refer to the parent class itself in the method:

```
class Parent(object):
    att = 'parent'

    def my_meth(self):
        return Parent.att + self.att

class Child(Parent):
    att = 'child'

print(Child().my_meth()) # parentchild
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the python [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) the super keyword Return a proxy object that delegates method calls to a parent or sibling class of type. You can not use this for member variables.